# Error al instalar eXelearning en Fedora 30

Tags: python, linux, dependencias, fedora

¡Saludos comunidad!

Por favor, necesito de su valiosa ayuda en el sentido de que he tratado de instalar el programa **`eXelearning`** en **`Fedora 30`** pero no lo consigo porque el **SO** arroja un "*Error de dependencias*", específicamente con los siguientes paquetes:

- `python-cssmin`
- `python-rjsmin`
- `python-webassets`

Estoy consciente que tal vez este tema esté un poco alejado de los tópicos que se suelen tratar aquí, pero he consultado en el foro de **`eXelearning`** y no he obtenido respuestas por lo que me veo en la necesidad de consultar con las ligas mayores.

No estoy seguro si el error de dependencias se debe a que solamente tengo instalado `Python 3` en mi **SO** y **`eXelearning`** esté diseñado para trabajar con `Python 2`.

Cuando trato de instalar cada paquete por separado el **SO** indica:

> No hay coincidencias para el argumento: python-cssmin
>    Error: No se pudo encontrar ningún resultado

Muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no me equivoco Fedora 30 proporciona el paquete para Python 3 (python3-cssmin) pero no para Python 2 (python-cssmin). La verdad es que si usan Python 2 ya están tardando demasiado en actualizar a Python 3... En Enero Python 2 se queda sin soporte oficial y no será porque  no se ha dado tiempo para portar proyectos.... De hecho la mayoría de las distros se han pasado hace tiempo a Python 3 y muchas librerías ya no dan soporte a Python 2 en sus nuevas versiones (como Pillow).

Comment: Tendrías que instalar Python 2 y obtener los paquetes desde PYPI u otras fuentes si es que fedora ya no los proporciona en los repos. ¿Has probado la versión portable en vez de instalar?

Comment: Saludos comunidad.

He dado con el siguiente link:  https://github.com/exelearning/iteexe/issues/413

Y me parece que la solución es esperar la migración total de eXelearning a Python 3 o esperar a una versión online.

¿Qué opinan?